# Can someone give me knowledge about how to use 'If Else' Statement if I need a condition to change a value on an temporary table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

- I have created a temporary table in a stored procedure.
- All the values have also been derived in #temptable.
  The problem is whenever I try to use a IF statement, it says "Invalid Column" although the column is available on the #temptable. Can somebody summarize me the logic behind it and what should be done for it to not happen again in the future.
  For example I have the column "availableBalance" on the #temptable.
  Now if I create a IF statement,

```
(This is just an example)
If (availableBalance>300)
Update status = 01
Else
Status = 02.
```

It will say "Invalid Column" AvailableBalance.

Please give me a briefing as to "Invalid Column" so that I can do it the right way ?

Comment: Your code example doesn't include _any_ table name. Why would you expect that the database would intuit that `availableBalance` and `status` should come from the table you have in mind? Aside: The data type of `status` is intriguing. The value may or may not have a decimal point and the leading zero is unlikely to be significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CASE/WHEN instead of IF/ELSE

```
 UPDATE #temptable
 SET status = 
     CASE 
         WHEN availableBalance > 300 THEN 0
         ELSE 02
     END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`IIF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** as

```
UPDATE #YourTable
SET Status = IIF(AvailableBalance > 300, 0, 1)
--WHERE condition if needed
```